# How can I make a Flex div and it's (image) children be contained within it's parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a responsive grid of images but I can't seem to make it work.
Either the images are responsive with a max-height and a max-width but the parent div doesn't take their full width (and therefore isn't contained within it's parent) or the images don't have a max-height and a max-width, their parent div has the correct width, but isn't responsive.
I hope I have made my problem and my goal clear. Can anyone shed some light on how can I achieve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e60tkhq/)

```css
#grid_area {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#grid {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="grid_area">
        <div id="grid">
            <div class="row" id="0">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/460x345/" id="A1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C1">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C2">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C3">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A4">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B4">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You are applying wrong Position to your div. Parent should be relative and child should be absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Grid. Give `max-width: (x)px` to your .grid-area.

Than in your grid-area you can create a grid 4x3

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Than every image that you add as a child will found a place in the grid.

and you can change your images positions inside Grid with `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties.

So i change #A1 image place inside grid with

```
#A1 {
grid-column: 2 / 3;
grid-row: 2/ 3;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.grid_area {
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#A1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2/ 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_area">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/460x345/" id="A1" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B1" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C1" />

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A2" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B2" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C2" />

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A3" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B3" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C3" />

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A4" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B4" />
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C4" />
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't let me set the maximum width of the grid to 50% and height to 80%...

Comment: i dont understand what did you mean ? when you apply percentages (%) it goes to parent element and take its widths 50% if parent element does not applied width value than it goes to grandparent element and use thats width 50% @HomuQB

Comment: The parent has a width, no? 100% of the viewport. I want the children to have 50% width of that and the contents inside of it to be resized to fit it. I'm sorry if I'm not making myself clear or if I'm failing to understand something really basic.

Comment: Okay i think i understand only thing that you need to change set `max-height:80%` `max-width: 50%;` and `margin:auto` in .grid_area , i edited the answer :) @HomuQB

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet->

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#grid_area {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

#grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  max-width: calc(100% / 3);
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    img {
      max-width: calc(100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="grid_area">
        <div id="grid">
            <div class="row" id="0">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C1">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="1">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C2">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="2">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C3">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="3">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A4">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B4">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Unfortunately the images are still not contained within the grid div using this.

Comment: @HomuQB Run the snippet and reply that this is what you need?

Comment: No, I wanted the content to be resized to fit the div without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. Remove the `absolute` positioning from the `#grid_area` parent as this will be problematic when expanding the design.

`width: 50%;` is not enough room for your content. I would remove the width altogether and let it render a width based on your content.

```css
#grid_area {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;  
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  object-fit: contain;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid_area">
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="row" id="0">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A1">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B1">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C1">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A2">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B2">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C2">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A3">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B3">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C3">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="A4">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="B4">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_chania.jpg" id="C4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose as I want the content to be resized to fit the 50% width.

Comment: @HomuQB You can see my edits. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but if you don't mind, upon further inspection I've noticed that this doesn't respect the maximum of 80% height. Is there any way I could achieve that?